# Application deployed to Kubernetes pod was creating pod successfully in Jenkins-X 2 but fails on Jenkins-X 3

Tags: kubernetes

I've inherited an application I need to deploy inside the cluster as a persistent pod to have access to other resources, but which only runs on demand when a user `kubectl exec`s into the pod. At initialisation I don't need it to do anything at all other than make the pod available for a user to `exec` into at a later date.

This works fine on our old Jenkins-X 2 cluster, but the new Jenkinx-X 3 version is going nowhere.

When it's deployed the status appears to go through a lifecycle of

```
Running
Completed
CrashLoopBackOff
```

However `kubectl logs -n <<namespace>> <<podname>> -p` shows no errors, and in `kubectl describe pod -n <<namespace>> <<podname>>` the `Containers/<<appname>>` section includes

```
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
```

Which looks inconsistent - I can't see how it's got into `CrashLoopBackoff` with a last state of `Terminated` because `Completed` and an `Exit Code` of 0 - the application, as far as I can see isn't failing, it's just that Kubernetes is shutting down the pod as completed rather than leaving it running, and it's then somehow getting stuck in CrashLoopBackoff.

I'd wondered whether this was something to do with readiness or liveness probes killing it through not finding a perpetually running process to service a request, but removing them or reverting to older versions doesn't seem to make any difference.

There's presumably something that's gone wrong in the charts between the old and new versions, but I'm running out of ideas on where to look. Is there anything people can suggest that might be causing this?

Comment: Is it any specific image that's used for this pod? What you described so far is absolutely correct. When process is ended, pod will be restarted by kubernetes. It depends on image/application inside the image. You can try both simple examples: 1st is busybox which will immediately ended and nginx which will continue running. Usually `sleep 86400` command is added to enforce pod from termination.

Comment: Also you can share the manifest of this pod in x2 and x3 versions to see what's the difference (I didn't work with Jenkins, but know kubernetes itself as platform, so we can find something or workaround as above)

Comment: Hello @eftpotrm. Any updates?